# Criteria API: Correct Date Format

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I am making a search module that will be able to filter data according to some criteria.

I already made the following:

```
public class SearchModuleBean implements Serializable{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    private Date departureDate;
    private Date returnDate;

    public List<Flight> search(){
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Flight> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Flight.class);
        Root<Flight> c = criteriaQuery.from(Flight.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(c).where(getPredicates(cb, c).toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        TypedQuery<Flight> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        System.out.println(query.getResultList());
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    private List<Predicate> getPredicates(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Flight> c) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        predicates.add(cb.equal(c.get(Flight_.departureDate), departureDate));
        return predicates;
    }
}
```

Getters/Setters/Annotations and imports are not displayed here.

I have a JSF page which fills in the departure- and arrivalDates.
In the getPredicates method I then check for the departureDate if it is equal to Dates in our database. The issue is that they have a different format so he never finds anything.

Comment: A Date in Criteria is not in any "format", it is a Java Date object. If you have a criteria query that you have problems with the first step would be to look at the SQL generated, and the column type in the datastore

Comment: Billy Frost is correct, one thing to check would be if the Dates are really equal in Java and in the database. java.util.Date can contain time information, if you're database only contains date-informationen they might not match (11-13-2018 12:00:00 != 11-13-2018 00:00:00).

Comment: This is correct and I knew that, the issue is that they indeed do not match because of the time. Can I only check for the date even if I have date and time in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't tend to use the Criteria API and there may be another way but you could possibly use the between operator as below:

```
private List<Predicate> getPredicates(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Flight> c, 
           Date departureDate) {

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    //remove time portion from specified date: now dd/mm/yy 00:00
    Date startDate = DateUtils.truncate(departureDate, Calendar.DATE);

    //new date with time initialized to 23:59:59
    Date endDate = DateUtils.addSeconds(DateUtils.addDays(startDate, 1), - 1);

    predicates.add(cb.between(c.get(Flight_.departureDate), startDate, endDate));

    return predicates;
}
```

DateUtils is a class in Commons Lang:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```